# How to split querySelectorAll result?

Tags: javascript, regex, loops, split

I have been able to querySelectorAll the correct className, a tag, and href. I am trying to split my result so I only have the SKU #.

HTML

```
   <div class="mini-cart-product-name">
   <a href="http://example.com/product/12345.html">Product 1</a>
   </div>

   <div class="mini-cart-product-name">
   <a href="http://example.com/product/67890.html">Product 2</a>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    function GetCartProducts() {

    var URL = document.querySelectorAll(".mini-cart-product-name a[href*='/product/']");
     for (var i = 0; i < URL.length; i++) {


    console.log(URL.item(i));

    <a href="http://example.com/product/12345.html">Product 1</a>
   </div>

   <a href="http://example.com/product/67890.html">Product 2</a>
    </div>

    // Split result/href to only have the SKU # //
    // Push to array
    // Desired result 
    // var array ["12345","67890"]
     }

     }
```

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not to familiar with regex. Would I use the regex before or after the loop?

Comment: Please see my answer for regular expression usage in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I just tried this out. What if My SKU is amix of numbers and letters. For example: FDUFG002. How would this change the expression?

Comment: It would change it quite a bit, as /d+ looks for occurences where numerics exist as 1 or more numeric characters.

Comment: I modified my answer to give you something that would work with a combination of letters and numbers using just `substring` and `replace` and `lastIndexOf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function can be a single line like this.

```js
function GetCartProducts() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".mini-cart-product-name a[href*='/product/']"))
    .map(el => el.href.replace(/^.+product\/(.+?)\.html.*?/i, '$1'))
}
console.log(GetCartProducts());
```

```html
<div class="mini-cart-product-name">
  <a href="http://example.com/product/12345.html">Product 1</a>
</div>

<div class="mini-cart-product-name">
  <a href="http://example.com/product/67890.html">Product 2</a>
</div>
```

Some explanations of `/^.+product\/(.+?)\.html/i`.
`/whatever/` is **Regular Expression**
`^` start of input
`.` any character `+` repeated one or more times
`\.` dot itself
`(.+?)` capturing pattern. `+?` one or more non-greedy
`$1` - captured text.

Comment: Thank you. This answer works well for my current needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regular expression to match the SKU #

```js
function GetCartProducts() {
    var SKUs = [];
    var URL = document.querySelectorAll(".mini-cart-product-name a[href*='/product/']");
    for (var i = 0; i < URL.length; i++) {
        SKUs[i] = URL[i].href.match(/\/(\d+)\.html/)[1];
    }
console.log(SKUs);
}
GetCartProducts();
```

```html
<div class="mini-cart-product-name">
   <a href="http://example.com/product/12345.html">Product 1</a>
   </div>

   <div class="mini-cart-product-name">
   <a href="http://example.com/product/67890.html">Product 2</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error when I execute this. Not sure if its me or a issue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Since you revised your criteria, you can do this with a simple string substring and replace
const skuNum = URL.item(i).substring(URL.item(i).lastIndexOf('/') + 1).replace('.html', '');    


//Don't use this if you have something other than numbers in the capture string, see above
//Declare your regular expression, this could be declared before your loop
const reg = /(\d+)\.html/g;
//These next two go inside your loop
//Get the match collection of captures from your regular expression
const matches = reg.exec(URL.item(i));
//Get your sku # from the match colletion
const skuNum = matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answer's mentioned before are correct, but such approach seems painfull.
If you can modify your html code i would suggest you to pass these SKU's as data attribute.

```
<div data-sku="12345" class="mini-cart-product-name">
    <a href="http://example.com/product/12345.html">Product 1</a>
</div>

<div data-sku="67890" class="mini-cart-product-name">
   <a href="http://example.com/product/67890.html">Product 2</a>
</div>
```

Then you need to modify your selector a bit so it doesn't 'cut' these attributes.

```
function GetCartProducts() {
    var SKUs = [];
    var URL = document.querySelectorAll(".mini-cart-product-name a");
    for (var i = 0; i < URL.length; i++) {
        SKUs[i] = URL[i].dataset.sku;
    }
    console.log(SKUs);
}
GetCartProducts();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is no way to modify the html at this point in time.